# Responsive design positioning spans

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two spans with inline-block display, in responsive mode (for resolution lower than 768X1024) I need to position one on top of the other so I set display to block but the wrong one is on top how can i make the second span to go on top?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this variation helps: 
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/RLSkL/

The important bits are that I flipped the order of the two divs in the HTML then used CSS to manage the layout

**CSS**

```
/* pull the first div to the right and the second to the left for desktop views */
#loginContent{
width:330px;
float:right;
}

#attensions{
width:330px;
float:left;
}

.LgnBtn{
clear:both;
}

/* for tablets and smartphones, remove the floats above */

@media (max-width: 790px){
#loginContent{
width:100%;
float:inherit;
}

#attensions{
width:100%
float:inherit;
}

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` on the `<div>` you'd like to be on top.

Comment: i've tried it out, no gain :|

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/parissa/aUJPm/ there are two spans #attensions and #loginContent when u resize it #attensions is on top i need #loginContent to be on top

Comment: Why not just move `#loginContent`'s HTML above `#attensions`? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mA8Zw/

Comment: i cant because in normal mode their positions must not change :/

Answer (score 0):

the only way is move up the #loginContent in your html code, in other hand you can use absolute position to set their position as you like. for exam:

```
#attensions{
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
}
#loginContent{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```